# Restrict SQL Server 2008 R2 User to restore only one database (but not others)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

It is my understanding that a user has to be a "dbcreator" in order to restore databases. However, what if I want a specific user to restore only one specific database, but not gain access or restore any other database on the server? Doesn't "dbcreator" allow that user to essentially restore any database?

Answer (score 3):

Log in as a server admin.
Create a stored procedure `with execute as owner` that restores a particular database.
Assign permission to execute it to the user.

As for where to put that stored procedure, I'm not sure it's possible to restore the DB from which you are running the SP, in which case you might want to create a completely blank database for the only purpose of storing this stored procedure.

Comment: +1 Alternatively to creating a blank database, you can put the procedure in master, model (which would allow you to execute it from tempdb) or in any utility database you have lying around. I actually thought about this solution while on a walk with my wife, and I'm glad someone posted it before I got back. I was thinking of this solely from the "prevent all except `x`" standpoint instead of the "allow only `x`" standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that you may be able to capture this with a server-level DDL trigger. However, `RESTORE_DATABASE` is an event I expected to see but is [not (yet?) supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542.aspx), and whether you are restoring a database from scratch or using `WITH REPLACE`, the `CREATE_DATABASE` event is not fired.

Of course even if `RESTORE_DATABASE` were a supported event, you wouldn't be able to conditionally prevent the actual restore, since create/restore database is not transactional and therefore cannot be rolled back (and DDL triggers are *after* triggers, not before/instead of triggers).

I think you would only be able to audit this activity and then respond after the fact, and I'm sure you could do this with an audit specification, or extended events, or trace, maybe even event notifications, etc.